# How can i illustrate a function that display value of function by color of pixel?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I 'd like to illustrate the function such that display the value of function by color of pixel in matlab. when the value of function is high the pixel's color be richly coloured and vice verse.

This is sample of such figure:

[image: figure]

I would be really appreciate if you help me how can i illustrate such figures in Matlab.

Comment: Could you write your function or an example?

Comment: a simple function like : S/(S+B+R) and this picture the x, axis is B and y axis is S.